# My PHP Session variable is passing more than my variable

Tags: php, html, session

I have a problem using php session to pass a url to a videoplayer in php. heres the code of the page that I want to pass the url

PHP CODE page1;

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($llenadoTabla))
{
    $f1 = $row['rutaPortada'];
    $f2 = $row['titulo'];
    $f3 = $row['rutaPelicula'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><img src="'.$f1.'" /></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $f2. '</td>';
    echo '<td> <a href="player2.php" role="button" class="btn btn-link btn-large" value ="';
    echo $_SESSION['url'] = $f3;
    echo '">Reproducir</a> </td>'; 
}
```

The value is passing with a button to another page 
PHP Code page2

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls id="videoplayer">
   <?php echo '<source src="'.$f3.'" type ="video/mp4">'; ?>
</div>
```

and the result of this session is this:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls id="videoplayer">
  <source src="192.168.5.161/Peliculas/movie.mp4"> "Reproducir"  type="video/mp4">  
</video
```

Comment: are you calling `session_start()`?

Comment: Yes there are in the top of my code, the problem is the session variable is passing the url and the label of my button, and i want that only pass the url that is saved in the $f3 variable

Comment: What's going on with `$_SESSION['url'] = $f3`  - surely that should return either truer or false.

Comment: the value of $_SESSION['url'] = $f3 when i pass to my player is this "192.168.5.161/Peliculas/movie.mp4"> "Reproducir" and i don´t know why is passing  >"Reproducir"

Comment: When/where are you setting `$_SESSION['url']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your original code before it was edited had this:

```
echo '<td> <a href="player2.php" role="button" class="btn btn-link btn-large" value ="'.$_SESSION['url'] = $f3.'">Reproducir</a> </td>';
```

I think that may explain why your output is `192.168.5.161/Peliculas/movie.mp4"> "Reproducir"  type="video/mp4">`.  The above code is equivalent to:

```
$_SESSION['url'] = $f3.'">Reproducir</a> </td>';
echo '<td> <a href="player2.php" role="button" class="btn btn-link btn-large" value ="'.$_SESSION['url'];
```

I am going to assume your `<?php echo '<source src="'.$f3.'" type ="video/mp4">'; ?>` is actually `<?php echo '<source src="'.$_SESSION['url'].'" type ="video/mp4">'; ?>` in your original code, since you are referring to passing session variables.  In that case, your output is actually

```
<source src="192.168.5.161/Peliculas/movie.mp4">Reproducir</a> </td>" type="video/mp4">
```

But in your browser rendered output, you do not see the hidden `</a>` and `</td>` tags.  The page view-source should show the true output.  So I think your code should really be:

```
echo '<td> <a href="player2.php" role="button" class="btn btn-link btn-large" value ="' . ($_SESSION['url'] = $f3) . '">Reproducir</a> </td>';
```

or better as:

```
$_SESSION['url'] = $f3;
echo '<td> <a href="player2.php" role="button" class="btn btn-link btn-large" value ="'.$_SESSION['url'].'">Reproducir</a> </td>';
```

Comment: I'd recommend using something like `sprintf()` here so you don't get these wonky difficult to manage echo statements that also just look like the backside of a steer. Other than that, spot on.